# Can I pass class method as and a default argument to another class method

Tags: python, class

I want to pass class method as and a default argument to another class method, so that I can reuse the method as a `@classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
class foo:
    def func1(self,x):
        do somthing;
    def func2(self, aFunc = self.func1):
        # make some a call to afunc
        afunc(4)
```

This is why when the method `func2` is called within the class `aFunc` defaults to `self.func1`, but I can call this same function from outside of the class and pass it a different function at the input.

I get:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Here is my setup:

```
class transmissionLine:  
    def electricalLength(self, l=l0, f=f0, gamma=self.propagationConstant, deg=False):
```

But I want to be able to call `electricalLength` with a different function for gamma, like:

```
transmissionLine().electricalLength (l, f, gamma=otherFunc)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083692/using-class-static-methods-as-default-parameter-values-within-methods-of-the-same for a great solution in a somewhat similar situation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using @classmethod on the class definition? I'm only familiar with its use on class methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Default argument values are computed during function definition, not during function call.  So no, you can't.  You can do the following, however:

```
def func2(self, aFunc = None):
    if aFunc is None:
        aFunc = self.func1
    ...
```

Comment: I really don't know that I completely understand the question that he is asking, but you have certainly identified the cause of the error that he is seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying wont work, because Foo isnt defined yet.

```
class Foo:  
  @classmethod
  def func1(cls, x):
    print 'something: ', cls, x

def func2(cls, a_func=Foo.func1):
 a_func('test')

Foo.func2 = classmethod(func2)

Foo.func2()
```

Comment: Hey i know thats not really a pythonic cool looking solution, but the question was "can i pass class method as and a default argument to another class method", and yes you could.

Comment: You are passing a function, not method binding here.  Method binding already includes the first argument (in this case it is `cls`), but function doesn't.  Try to use your suggestion and you will see that call to `a_func` won't work because there's not enough arguments.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. It looks viable to me. doublep is wrong, the code runs in Python 2.6 as written.

Comment: I was wrong indeed.  Didn't consider that `self` is not needed for a classmethod and `Foo.func1` is actually a method binding for a classmethod.  Even for a normal method it is a binding though it cannot be called without class object.

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def func1(cls, x):
        print x
    def func2(self, afunc=None):
        if afunc is None:
            afunc = self.func1
        afunc(4)
```

Though it would be helpful if you gave a little more info on what you are trying to do.  There is probably a more elegant way to do this without classmethods.

Comment: @alex -- the above is hard to read in a comment. Edit your question and add it there