# Using class/static methods as default parameter values within methods of the same class

Tags: python, decorator, default-value, class-method, static-methods

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class SillyWalk(object):
    @staticmethod
    def is_silly_enough(walk):
        return (False, "It's never silly enough")
    def walk(self, appraisal_method=is_silly_enough):
        self.do_stuff()
        (was_good_enough, reason) = appraisal_method(self)
        if not was_good_enough:
            self.execute_self_modifying_code(reason)
        return appraisal_method
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass
    def execute_self_modifying_code(self, problem):
        from __future__ import deepjuju
        deepjuju.kiss_booboo_better(self, problem)
```

with the idea being that someone can do

```
>>> silly_walk = SillyWalk()
>>> appraise = walk()
>>> is_good_walk = appraise(silly_walk)
```

and also get some magical machine learning happening; this last bit is not of particular interest to me, it was just the first thing that occurred to me as a way to exemplify the use of the static method in both an in-function context and from the caller's perspective.

Anyway, this doesn't work, because `is_silly_enough` is not actually a function: it is an object whose `__get__` method will return the original `is_silly_enough` function.  This means that it only works in the "normal" way when it's referenced as an object attribute.  The object in question is created by the `staticmethod()` function that the decorator puts in between `SillyWalk`'s `is_silly_enough` attribute and the function that's originally defined with that name.

This means that in order to use the default value of `appraisal_method` from within *either* `SillyWalk.walk` *or* its caller, we have to either

- call `appraisal_method.__get__(instance, owner)(...)` instead of just calling `appraisal_method(...)`
- or assign it as the attribute of some object, then reference that object property as a method that we call as we would call `appraisal_method`.

Given that neither of these solutions seem particularly Pythonic™, I'm wondering if there is perhaps a better way to get this sort of functionality.  I essentially **want a way to specify that a method should, by default, use a particular class or static method defined within the scope of the same class to carry out some portion of its daily routine.**

I'd prefer not to use `None`, because I'd like to allow `None` to convey the message that that particular function should not be called.  I guess I could use some other value, like `False` or `NotImplemented`, but it seems a) hackety b) annoying to have to write an extra couple of lines of code, as well as otherwise-redundant documentation, for something that seems like it could be expressed quite succinctly as a default parameter.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe all you need is to use the function (and not the method) in the first place?

```
class SillyWalk(object):
    def is_silly_enough(walk):
        return (False, "It's never silly enough")

    def walk(self, appraisal_function=is_silly_enough):
        self.do_stuff()
        (was_good_enough, reason) = appraisal_function(self)
        if not was_good_enough:
            self.execute_self_modifying_code(reason)
        return appraisal_function
    def do_stuff(self):
        pass
    def execute_self_modifying_code(self, problem):
        deepjuju.kiss_booboo_better(self, problem)
```

Note that the default for appraisal_function will now be a function and not a method, even though is_silly_enough will be bound as a class method once the class is created (at the end of the code).

This means that

```
>>> SillyWalk.is_silly_enough
<unbound method SillyWalk.is_silly_enough>
```

but

```
>>> SillyWalk.walk.im_func.func_defaults[0] # the default argument to .walk
<function is_silly_enough at 0x0000000002212048>
```

And you can call is_silly_enough with a walk argument, or call a walk instance with .is_silly_enough().

If you really wanted is_silly_enough to be a static method, you could always add

```
    is_silly_enough = staticmethod(is_silly_enough)
```

anywhere after the definition of walk.

Comment: +1 That's pretty close to what I had in mind.  I was thinking more about the general case, though, where `is_silly_walk` would, like a typical static method, not take an argument of the instance type.  I guess I could do something like `is_silly_enough = staticmethod(functools.partial(is_silly_enough, None))` after the declaration of `walk` to provide the extraneous parameter so outside callers wouldn't have to.  I guess the downside there is that the function signature would cease to serve as accurate documentation.

Comment: Sorry, that last comment didn't make sense.  With the `staticmethod(...)` call placed after the declaration of the function that uses the static-to-be as a default parameter value, this works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Can someone comment on the pros/cons between this answer and the answer from OP (below)? I posted a question about it, but no answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971490/static-method-as-default-parameter-to-a-class-method Thanks!

Comment: I think the OP is using "method" in the English sense, not the OOP sense, i.e. "the method of appraisal" becomes "appraisal_method", so no need to call it appraisal_function.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing an (un)wrapper function, to be used within function definition headers, eg

```
def walk(self, appraisal_method=unstaticmethod(is_silly_enough)):
```

This actually seems to work, at least it makes my doctests that break without it pass.

Here it is:

```
def unstaticmethod(static):
    """Retrieve the original function from a `staticmethod` object.

    This is intended for use in binding class method default values
      to static methods of the same class.

    For example:
        >>> class C(object):
        ...     @staticmethod
        ...     def s(*args, **kwargs):
        ...         return (args, kwargs)
        ...     def m(self, args=[], kwargs={}, f=unstaticmethod(s)):
        ...         return f(*args, **kwargs)
        >>> o = C()
        >>> o.s(1, 2, 3)
        ((1, 2, 3), {})
        >>> o.m((1, 2, 3))
        ((1, 2, 3), {})
    """
    # TODO: Technically we should be passing the actual class of the owner
    #         instead of `object`, but
    #         I don't know if there's a way to get that info dynamically,
    #         since the class is not actually declared
    #         when this function is called during class method definition.
    #       I need to figure out if passing `object` instead
    #         is going to be an issue.
    return static.__get__(None, object)
```

#### update:

I wrote doctests for the `unstaticmethod` function itself; they pass too.  I'm still not totally sure that this is an actual smart thing to do, but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get exactly what you're after, but would it be cleaner to use getattr?

```
>>> class SillyWalk(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ise(walk):
        return (False, "boo")
    def walk(self, am="ise"):
        wge, r = getattr(self, am)(self)
        print wge, r


>>> sw = SillyWalk()
>>> sw.walk("ise")
False boo
```

Comment: could be a workaround, I guess.  I'd like to be able to override the default by passing a callable, and I'd also like the default case to be the fastest.  Also it's not quite self-evident that "ise" is meant to be the name of a static method.  I guess I'm looking for a function named something like `undecorate_static_method`.  Which I suppose I could write, and include with every module that I wanted to use this pattern in.. so as to be able to make the `def` line `def walk(self, am=undecorate_static_method(ise)):`